# How to display the option in the field after selecting an option in autosuggest?

Tags: jquery, html

Im using jquery for autocomplete feature and getting data from database.Autocomplete is working fine but the problem is..when I select any option from the list, I need that option to be populate in the current page after pressing submit button.
 Im new to jquery....Any help is appriciated.

```
<h3>Country</h3>
<form action="">
    <input type="text" id="country1" name="country1">
    <p>
        <label>State</label>
        <br>
    </p>
</form>
<script> $("#country").autocomplete("Data.jsp"); </script>
```

Comment: My code is...<h3>Country</h3>
 <form action="">
 
 <input type="text"  id="country1" name="country1"/>
  <p><label >State</label><br />
  
 </form>
 <script>
  $("#country").autocomplete("Data.jsp");
    
 </script>

Comment: By using autocomplete.js plugin Im getting the autocomplete feature

Comment: Are you using [jquery ui autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) plugin.

Comment: So you are not able to get the value when select or you are getting the value just want to place it somewhere in your page?

Comment: I want to print the selected value on the same page..

Comment: For eg., If i'm typing 'a' in the input field...i'm getting some suggestions like a,app,apple...then if I select 'apple', that 'apple' need to be displayed just below the text box.

Comment: look below I have answered that. That will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is `select` method for [jquery autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data). Here in this below code you can assign the selected value to a DIV having id `yourDIVId`.

```
select: function( event, ui ) {
    $('#yourDIVId').html(ui.item.value);

}
```

Comment: You can place the value where ever you want on your DOM as per your need!

Comment: Im getting an error like this--"Syntax error on token "function", if expected"

Comment: Can you please add your code in jsfiddle. So that I can look into that. This way I'm not sure where the error is!

Comment: It's not working. Where is the dataset? Please look into this [example](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote). Here you can check view source how it's done.

Comment: I created one java file which has JDBC connection and one jsp(Data.jsp) file which is used to get the data from "autocomplete.js" and kept in the 'List' and printing..